# Localhost requests from referer are blocked

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to run this project call thing translator from https://github.com/dmotz/thing-translator and I found this error while running it.

It says:

```
{error: {code: 403, message: "Requests from referer http://localhost/www/index.html are blocked.",…}}
```

Comment: You need to set up your API key.

Comment: @SLaks i've already set up the API key. Still not working.

Comment: You need to set it up to allow that referer.

Comment: May I know which referrer are you talking about?

Answer (score 8):

Check your Google Cloud API key restriction.
[image]